# Detect that TPM Dictionary Attack Reset has been done

Tags: uefi, tpm, lockout

Is there a way to detect from code that a dictionary attack reset has been attempted, but with the wrong lockoutAuth value?

I can detect that the TPM is in lockout by checking to see if failedTries == maxTries.  I cant seem to find a way to know that a reset has failed and the TPM is in lockout due to an incorrect lockoutAuth value.

I am aware that I can attempt a DA protected operation and observe the TPM_RC_LOCKOUT return, but I wondered if there was a way without attempting an operation.

I am in a UEFI environment, this is not that important but I should mention it.

Regards

Ben